# Cookie not being passed on subsequent requests

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, rest, spring-mvc

I am having a problem with passing a cookie while trying to make subsequent requests with AJAX to my Spring MVC controller.

For e.g. I have a `/login` endpoint to which I pass some JSON via POST method and it sets the cookie. I see the cookie in the firebug:

[image]

As you can see it is there. I am creating a cookie like this:

```
NewCookie cookie = new NewCookie(new Cookie(SECURITY_TICKET, encodedTicket, configKey, null), null, (int) TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(expireTime), expireTimeDate, false, false)
```

And setting it to HTTP headers:

```
httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.SET_COOKIE, cookie.toString());
```

Then these headers are being added to ResponseEntity like this:

```
ResponseEntity entity = new ResponseEntity<>(this.entity, this.httpHeaders, this.status)
```

And this response entity is returned. My conroller's methods are all REST based.

So then I am trying to call the other (`/search`) endpoint after successful login which functionality is expecting the cookie and it obviosly fails because for some reason cookie is not being passed back.

My AJAX calls looks like this:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/dev-citigroup-citi/login',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '{ "username": "client1", "password": "*******", "platform": "iOS", "UUID": "321321321", "application": "CitiReach", "applicationVersion": "1.0" }',
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/dev-citigroup-citi/search/eventattendee?q=*:*&start=0&rows=1&wt=json&indent=true',
                type: 'GET',
                xhrFields: { withCredentials:true },
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
        }
    });
});
```

As I mentioned the `/login` is OK but the other call fails. I am adding `xhrFields: { withCredentials:true }` which should be including the cookie in the `/search` request but for some reason it is not.

I also have CORS being set up correctly:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:63342
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

`http://localhost:63342` is the origin where the request comes from, it is configured in the CORS headers.

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, so rather than having `xhrFields: { withCredentials:true }` on the method level, I've put it globaly:

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    });
```

And cookie is passed now within the subsequent requests. No idea why it doesn't work on method level, maybe a bug in jquery...

jQuery version I was using: 2.1.3

Maybe this will help someone in future.